# fatal error C1047: The object or library file '*was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries

Tags: visual-c++

```
fatal error C1047: The object or library file '.\Release\stdafx.obj' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries
```

im using VisualStudio 2008, when im trying to compile im getting error of .obj file was created with older compiler.

**Clean / Rebuild**
**Manually deleted files from release/debug**

Comment: So you're saying you manually deleted the Release directory, the stdafx.obj file is recreated, and you get this error when you rebuild? When I've seen this issue before it was because the precompiled header setup was incorrect and the stdafx.obj file was leftover from a previous build. Manually removing the entire Debug/Release directory fixed the issue as would fixing the precompiled header settings.